# Loop through json from a page

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through some data received from a page, and if the price of the item (it's in the data) is under a certain amount I want to make an alert. But I was wondering how I can successfully loop through all the data from this site.

http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=1&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2

I think I can do the part of the alerts and such if I can just figure out the looping.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var myjson;
    var page = 1;
    $.getJSON("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber="+page+"&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2", function(json){
        myjson = json;
        alert(myjson[0].Description);
    });
    //var new_json = JSON.parse(myjson);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Convert it to JSON Object and use for loop. There are hundreds of similar questions. Search first.

Comment: @GokhanArik - There is no such thing as JSON Object in JavaScript though.

Comment: I am not talking about dictionary definition of `JSON Object`. It is obvious that I am talking about JavaSCript Object that contains parsed JSON Data. In that case he doesn't need to do that, anyway getJSON will return JSON data, he just needs to loop thru it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.getJSON("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber="+page+"&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2", function(json){

    $.each(json, function(i, field){
        console.log(field["Description"]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON string to an object.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "foo": "bar" }' );

alert( obj.foo );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2xcT/